# How to change images when selecting an option for Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am confused on how to display a picture when selecting an option. For example, I select Spring from the option in HTML and it is supposed to link from external source Javascript. A picture is supposed to appear a Spring picture. I did tried using if statements, if a value = "Spring" then an image will appear.

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <img src="" name="changepic">
        <select name="allseasons" id="allseasons">
            <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
            <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
            <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
            <option value="Winter">Winter</option>
        </select>
    </body>
    </html>

Javascript

element=document.getElementById('allseasons');
if (value =="spring");
    element.src="spring.jpg"
if (value =="summer"); 
    element.src="summer.jpg"
if (value =="fall"); 
    element.src="fall.jpg"
if (value =="winter"); 
    element.src="winter.jpg"
}
```

Comment: One equals sign assigns. Two compare. Three are used for type comparison. You want `if (value == "spring")` or `if (value === "spring")`. Also, your `else` condition has no brackets and will throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

- You should attach event listener to `<select>`
- Secondly you should store the `src` in the `value` of `<option>` so you don't need to check every `src`.
- Donot put `;` at end of your `if` statement.It will always run the code below it either the condition is true or false

  ```js
  const element = document.querySelector('#changepic');
  console.log(element);
  document.querySelector('#allseasons').addEventListener('change',(e) => {
    element.src = e.target.value;
    console.log(element);
  })
  ```

  ```html
  <img src="" name="changepic" id="changepic">
      <select name="allseasons" id="allseasons">
          <option value="spring">Spring</option>
          <option value="summer">Summer</option>
          <option value="fall">Fall</option>
          <option value="winter">Winter</option>
      </select>
  ```